# State directly on "this"

Tags: reactjs

A lot of people use properties directly on `this` (*e.g* `this.clickCount`) instead of `this.state` object and sometimes there's like 20 different properties attached directly to `this`.

Is `this.state` purely for organization or is there something else about it? Why are so many people / projects not using `this.state`?

Both following examples work  exactly the same way.

---

### Code example with state:

```js
class Clicker extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = {
            clickCount: 0
        }

        this._onClick= this._onClick.bind(this)
    }

    render() {
        return (

            <button onClick={this._onClick}>
                Clicked {this.state.clickCount} times
            </button>
        )
    }

    _onClick() {
        this.setState({
            clickCount: this.state.clickCount + 1
        })
    }
}
```

### Code example without state:

```js
class Clicker extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super()

        this._onClick= this._onClick.bind(this)
    }

    render() {
        return (

            <button onClick={this._onClick}>
                Clicked {this.clickCount ? this.clickCount : 0} times
            </button>
        )
    }

    _onClick() {
        this.clickCount = (this.clickCount ? this.clickCount : 0) + 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are cases when you'll want just instance variables that are unrelated to `state`. For these just do something like `this.<INSTANCE-VARIABLE>`.

When you want your component to re-render whenever a value is changed, you're better off attaching that value to `state` and modifying it using `this.setState(..)`.

Answer (score 0):

The first example will trigger a re-render of the component when `_onClick` is called because the state is changed.

The second example will not trigger a re-render of the component when `_onClick` is called, so you might not see the updated value for some time (until something else makes the component render again).